# XPaths using EclipseLink MOXy and JAXB given a value of another element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb, moxy

I want to get the text value of a certain element in xml. In the XML below i want to get the value of SUBCHILD when the value of CODE is 'Code1' irrespective of the position of the MP entity when there could be many MP elements. Also i want to be able to do this using JAXB and MOXy with the @XMLPath attribute

The xml i have is this:

```
<RQ>
    <PQ>
      <MP>
        <INFO>
          <CODE>Code1</CODE>
         </INFO>
        <CHILD>
          <SUBCHILD>VALUE for Code1</SUBCHILD>
        </CHILD>
        </MP>
          <MP>
        <INFO>
          <CODE>Code2</CODE>
          </INFO>
        <CHILD>
          <SUBCHILD>VALUE for Code2</SUBCHILD>
        </CHILD>
        </MP>
 </PQ>
</RQ>
```

I want 'VALUE for Code1' irrespecive of its position, the MP element containing Code1 could be anywhere. The XPath i would use for this would be:

```
RQ/PQ/MP[INFO/CODE='Code1']/CHILD/SUBCHILD
```

but i cant seem to get the value i want from MOXy, is this functionality not supported, I know that you can map based on attributes, but i need it depending on the value of another element

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOXy currently does not support XPaths of the following form on its `@XmlPath` annotation.

There is an open bug to have an exception thrown if the XPath specified is not supported.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/397101

Can you open an enhancement request for the behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to but i'm not sure that i can as i am not an eclipse member, Another one i found i needed was: getting a value based on the attribute of its tag equaling the attribute value of another tag